# Some hypersurface has a positive second fundamental form potentially

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, metric-geometry

Notation : $r^2=x^2+y^2$

Exercise : Define $$F_\sigma (x,y)= (f_\sigma
(x,y),\frac{x^2-y^2}{2},xy)$$ where $$f_\sigma (x,y)=(1- \sigma^2
r^2)(x-\sigma x^3,y-\sigma y^3)$$

Define $ G_\sigma: \mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow
\mathbb{R}^4$ by
$$G_\sigma(x,y,a,b)=(dF_\sigma )_{(x,y)} (a,b)  =(
 (df_\sigma)_{(x,y)}(a,b) ,R(x,y))$$ where $R$ is $\angle ((a,b),(1,0))$-rotation

Then there is a sequence of balls $U_\sigma$ and unit circle $S$ s.t. $\lim_{\sigma\rightarrow 0}\ {\rm diam}\ U_\sigma =0$ and $G_\sigma (U_\sigma \times S)$ has positive second fundamental form.

And $G_0 (U\times S)$, homeomorphic to solid torus, has no positive second fundamental form for any ball $U$ (These are obatined from direct computation)

> **Question :** Intuitively, how can we vary $G_0 (U\times S)$ so that $G_\sigma
> (U_\sigma\times S)$ has a positive second fundamental form ?

**Reference :** On intrinsic geometry of surface in normed spaces  - Burago and Ivanv

My solution : Exercise (cf. Reference) : Hypersurface has a positive second
fundamental form at $p$ if there is a linear function $L$ and $c>0$
s.t. $L(q)\leq L(p)- c|q-p|^2$ for all $q$ in a neighborhood of $p$

If $ F_0(x,y)=(x,y,\frac{x^2-y^2}{2},xy)$, then $dF_0\ U\times S$
has out normal $W$ at a point $(a,b,0,0),\ (a,b)\in S$.

$ \langle W,(a,b,0,0) -(a_0,b_0,0,0)\rangle \leq -c
 \{ |(a,b)-(a_0,b_0)|^2+|(x,y)|^2\}$ does not hold since there is a
 term $|(x,y)|^2$.

Hence we have a strategy to find $f_\sigma$ s.t. $|
(df_\sigma)_{(x,y)}(a,b) -(a,b)| \leq O(x^2,xy,y^2)
$

Comment: Explanation in bounty space can be ignored. I want to know the question in OP.

Comment: Cross-posted on MathOF: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313974/some-hypersurface-has-a-positive-second-fundamental-form-potentially

Comment: You should avoid posting a bounty here simultaneously as posting on MO. Posting on MO seems very reasonable and the delay between the post here and there (3 weeks) is very reasonable. But now the question takes place on MO, it should better not be cross-discussed here too (to avoid double discussion). Actually, since there has been no comment/answer at all, I would have even find reasonable to delete the question here.

Comment: Thank you for your using way, and I can not delete this question by this site rule.

Comment: I see, maybe precisely because of the bounty. Hopefully the discussion will take place on MathOF anyway.

Comment: Yes, if there is a discussion here, then I will write it in OP in MO.